# JSLint insists that "Unexpected 'call'"

Tags: call, jslint

JSLint insists that there's something wrong with this use of .call:

```
function GridView(tableArray, tableId, multiselect) {
    "use strict";
    if (multiselect == undefined) {
        this.multiselect = false;
    } else {
        this.multiselect = multiselect;
    }

    this.tableID = tableId;
    this.propertiesArr = [];
    this.tableHTML = undefined;
    this.oTable = undefined;

    this._constructTable.call(this, tableArray);

}
```

Is wrong. Well, Unexpected, anyway. I just can't for the life of me figure out why, is there something wrong with the code? It seems to work, but I'm worried about unexpected behavior.

Comment: If `_constructTable` is already available on the instance (presumably via `GridView.prototype`), why do you need to use `.call`? Can't you just do `this._constructTable(tableArray);`?

Comment: @James Allardice: I don't, and yes I can. I'm mostly experimenting with 'call' right now. So is JSLint clever enough to see that the code is dumb?

Comment: It seems to be, yes. If you remove `this.` from before `_constructTable`, or change `this` to anything else in the `.call`, JSLint no longer warns.

Comment: @James Allardice: Well that puts my mind to ease, I thought there's something terribly wrong with .call I just didn't know abut. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesAllardice should probably post that as the answer, as he's right on the money.  It's certainly conventionally unexpected to send "this" as the context for `call`, and that's what it's choking on.  ;^)

Comment: @James Allardice: If you want your well-deserved rep, feel free to actually post it as an answer. Otherwise I'll just answer the question myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause of the warning is the following line:

```
this._constructTable.call(this, tableArray);
```

This construct appears to be largely pointless - you are calling the `_constructTable` method in the context of `this`, which would be the same context it would be called in if you called it via a normal call expression. JSLint is expecting exactly that:

```
this._constructTable(tableArray);
```